# Sending WindowsIndentity to a WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, windows-identity

I'm trying to send a WindowsIdentity to a Web service, but I have a compilation error I don't understand. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

The folowing method is on the web service:

```
WindowsIdentity wi;
[WebMethod]
public void getWI(WindowsIdentity wi)
{
    this.wi = wi;
}
```

Client side, the Web Service is called WSTest and I gave the namespace WS:

```
public void Test()
{
    WindowsIdentity wd = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    WS.WStestSoapClient clt = new WS.WStestSoapClient();
    clt.getWI(wd); // <- error is here
}
```

The error is :

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' to 'WSCommunicationTest.WS.WindowsIdentity'

I don't understand why WindowsIdentity are different client and server side, is it a security measure? And is it possible to send a WindowsIdentity by args?

Comment: If you create the client by adding a reference to your asmx, the generated wrapper classes encapsulate the original ones, so types don't match

Comment: @B.Lec but why does it work with other kind of object then?